# Programmatically Install Driver For MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, installation

We have a C# 4.0 (VS2010) application that requires installation of a MYSQL (driver) Connector)... We don't want the user to manually install it.. Is there a way to do this programmatically? through a DLL COM Registration etc?

What are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official MySQL site, [there is a zip package available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-installation-windows.html), which includes the source files of their installer. You should be able to include that installer in a WiX project and build a convenient solution by installing it via the [WiX toolset](http://wix.codeplex.com/) programatically.

You could also use the MySQL conector.msi which can be installed in unattended mode via the commandline switch /quiet:

```
msiexec /package conector-net.msi /quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

why not create a regular install for that? you can create setup project with Visual Studio or maybe use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) setup tool.